# Error:(13,28) java: package com.aliasi.tokenizer does not exist

Tags: java, intellij-idea, import, jar

I have intelliJ IDEA and demo sources from a book: it complains about the mentioned import in the title! Even if I include the downloaded jar into a lib folder and add it as a library... BTW I use mvn to build, but mvn central repository of the library does not exist anymore, so I have to go with the jar library.

How do I correctly include library jar into intelliJ IDEA project?

Comment: `File > Project Structure > Libraries > + > Java > Browse your Jar file`

Comment: I already have lib folder with jar added in Project structure... even adding jar itself does not solve the import error!

Answer (score 0):

intelliJ IDEA:

Build - Rebuild project

did the trick!